# If else condition for button, Grails

Tags: java, grails, if-statement, gsp

I'm looking for controller codes in Grails for buttons if/else.

I've got the codes for radio button, when the user selects :

```
<g:radio name="myGroup" value ="input2" />


if (request.getParameter("myGroup").equals("input1"))
        {

        println("asdasdasdasdasdhelloipass")
        redirect (action: radio)

        }
```

This is how it works, but for buttons, what is the if condition for it when the user click on the button. Thanks in advance.

```
 <g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="abc"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you're trying to do? The "actionSubmit" tag will submit the form parameters to an action called "abc".

```
class SomeController {

    def index() { }

def abc() {
        log.debug("called abc")
    }
}
```

some/index.gsp

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:form>
            <g:actionSubmit value="blah" action="abc"/>
        </g:form>
    </body>
</html>
```